# Limit of a complex series

Tags: limits

I have this limit I am trying to prove. Any suggestions on how to prove it is appreciated.

Prove

- When $|z|<1$, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}$$
- When $|z| > 1$, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(z) = \infty$$

Where $$S_n(z) = \frac{1-z^n}{1-z}$$

I am a Computer Engineering major so I am little rusty on limits. Do I substitute $z = x+iy$ in the series and simplify then calculate the limit?

Comment: If you're rusty, start with something simpler: What happens with $z^n$ as $n\to\infty$? (If you don't see it right away, use polar form.)

Comment: I believe it goes to infinitie. Using the polar form z^n = (r^n)e^(i.n.theta) also goes to infiniti if r >1. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $|z| > 1 \Rightarrow |S_n(z)|\geq \dfrac{|z|^n - 1}{|z-1|}\to +\infty$ rightaway when $n \to \infty$, and for $|z| < 1,  S_n(z) = \dfrac{1}{1-z} - \dfrac{z^n}{1-z}$, and $\left|\dfrac{z^n}{1-z}\right|=\dfrac{|z|^n}{|1-z|} \to 0$ when $n \to \infty \Rightarrow S_n(z) \to \dfrac{1}{1-z}$.

Comment: I tried constructing Sn(z) from the geometric series sigma (z^n) from n=0 to infiniti this way:
Partial sum SN:
SN= sigma (z^n) from n = 0 to infiniti = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + … + z^N ===>
z . SN = z + z^2 + z^3 + … + z^(N+1) ====>
(1-z) SN = 1-Z^(N+1) ====>
SN = (1-z^(N+1))/(1-z)

We know that the geometric series converges for |z| <1 and diverges for |z|>1 
Is there any way I can construct SN = (1-z^(N))/(1-z) the same way?